# Where should I ask for recommendation on (possibly) existing programming plugins?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm looking into developing an ordering app for a potential client. The main part that I'm concerned about in this question is the payment mechanism. I would assume that there are already multiple plugins or similar programs out there, but I'm not sure where (or if) I should be asking for recommendations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask for software recommendations on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Be sure to [provide enough information](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: Is it on-topic to ask for plugins there?

Comment: @Ben I think so, but I am not an expert on the site.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll check it out